# Is safe to restart Dbus daemon after system update?

Tags: linux, operating-system, debian, dbus

Is safe to restart *Dbus* daemon after update on production system ?

Services and daemons use dynamically linked libraries and I use service *Needrestart* to determine which service should be restarted.

Updates in eg. *libc6* causes restart for almost all daemons. I do not allow myself to restart *Dbus* (which provides communication interface across the system). Is there any potential risk to data loss, deadlock, ...?

My environment is based on Debian (Wheezy, Jessie) with services provides SMTP, HTTP, DNS, DHCP, SMB, FTP, etc... but no X applications.